# Containers not loading with `nginx-proxy`

Tags: docker, nginx

I have 4 containers as per the docker-compose file below (I've combined the `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` files):

```
version: '3'
services:

  #App Service
  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: my-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "9090:80"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_PROTO: fastcgi
      VIRTUAL_HOST: www.domain.com,domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: www.domain.com,domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: myemail@domain.com
      APP_ENV: production
      CONTAINER_ROLE: app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    working_dir: /var/www
    networks:
      - app-network
      - nginx-proxy

  #Admin Service
  admin:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/admin/Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: app-admin
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "9191:80"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_PROTO: fastcgi
      VIRTUAL_HOST: admin.domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: admin.domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: myemail@domain.com
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/admin
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    working_dir: /var/www/admin
    networks:
      - app-network
      - nginx-proxy

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: app-mysql
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      MYSQL_USER: db-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: randompassword
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: randomrootpassword
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:ro
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: app-phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9091:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: randomrootpassword
      VIRTUAL_HOST: phpmyadmin.domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: phpmyadmin.domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: myemail@domain.com
    networks:
      - app-network
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
  nginx-proxy:
    external: true
```

These are all behind `nginx-proxy` and `etsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` with the following setup:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx-proxy:
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:1.3-alpine
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
        environment:
          - SHA1_UPSTREAM_NAME=true
        networks:
         - nginx-proxy
        labels:
         - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy" 
        volumes: 
         - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
         - ./volumes/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
         - ./volumes/logs:/var/log/nginx
         - "nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
         - "html:/usr/share/nginx/html"
         - "certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro"
    letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        volumes:
         - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
         - ./volumes/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
         - "nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
         - "html:/usr/share/nginx/html"
         - "certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw"
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
        networks:
            - nginx-proxy
networks:
  nginx-proxy:
    external: true
volumes:
    nginx-conf:
    html:
    certs:
```

When I go to the `{myIp}`:9091, phpMyAdmin loads fine and I can use it with no issues. However, when I go to `{myIp}`:9090 or `{myIp}`:9191, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I have checked `ufw` but that's not even installed. When I run `netstat -tulpn` I see this:

[image]

When I run `iptables` I see this:

[image]

I am not sure what else to check. The `access.log` for nginx is empty. The `error.log` for nginx shows no errors. Both the logs for the containers show `Ready to accept connections`. Locally, it all runs (but I'm running only `app-network` not the `nginx-proxy`. Why can't I access the containers through the ip addresses?

Comment: What's `{myIp}` in your example ?

Comment: A public IP address.